# Scalar vs List Assignment Operator

Tags: perl, assignment-operator

Please help me understand the following snippets:

- `my $count = @array;`
- `my @copy = @array;`
- `my ($first) = @array;`
- `(my $copy = $str) =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;`
- `my ($x) = f() or die;`
- `my $count = () = f();`
- `print($x = $y);`
- `print(@x = @y);`

Comment: could you add an explicit question?  there isn't one

Comment: `my ($first) = @array`

Comment: @ysth, Technically, there are 8 questions. But feel free to rewrite.

Comment: @mob, Of course! Added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*This answer is also found in table format [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129).*]

The symbol `=` is compiled into one of two assignment operators:

- A *list assignment operator* (`aassign`) is used if the left-hand side (LHS) of a `=` is some kind of aggregate.
- A *scalar assignment operator* (`sassign`)  is used otherwise.

The following are considered to be aggregates:

- Any expression in parentheses (e.g. `(...)`)
- An array (e.g. `@array`)
- An array slice (e.g. `@array[...]`)
- A hash (e.g. `%hash`)
- A hash slice (e.g. `@hash{...}`)
- Any of the above preceded by `my`, `our` or `local`

There are two differences between the operators.

### Context of Operands

The two operators differ in the context in which their operands are evaluated.

- The scalar assignment evaluates both of its operands in scalar context.

  ```
    # @array evaluated in scalar context.
    my $count = @array;
  ```
- The list assignment evaluates both of its operands in list context.

  ```
    # @array evaluated in list context.
    my @copy = @array;
  ```

  ```
    # @array evaluated in list context.
    my ($first) = @array;
  ```

### Value(s) Returned

The two operators differ in what they return.

- The scalar assignment ...

  - ... in scalar context evaluates to its LHS as an lvalue.

    ```
      # The s/// operates on $copy.
      (my $copy = $str) =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
    ```
  - ... in list context evaluates to its LHS as an lvalue.

    ```
      # Prints $x.
      print($x = $y);
    ```
- The list assignment ...

  - ... in scalar context evaluates to the number of scalars returned by its RHS.

    ```
      # Only dies if f() returns an empty list.
      # This does not die if f() returns a
      # false scalar like zero or undef.
      my ($x) = f() or die;
    ```

    ```
      # $counts gets the number of scalars returns by f().
      my $count = () = f();
    ```
  - ... in list context evaluates to the scalars returned by its LHS as lvalues.

    ```
      # Prints @x.
      print(@x = @y);
    ```

Comment: change to say just array or hash or array or hash slice, to be inclusive of the postderef syntax

Comment: @ysth, Ah yes, those didn't exists when this was [originally written](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)