# what's the difference between (variable) = @_ and variable = @_

Tags: perl, parameter-passing

i am learning perl, want to call a function, and pass 2 parameters to it, 
here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnins;

sub test
{
 my ($item) = @_;
 print "$item\n";
}

test("hello world");
```

the result is : hello world

if i change the code to be like this:

```
my $item = @_;
```

then the result is: 1

what's the reason for the difference ? a little confused,
i understand @_ is the parameter passed to function test when calling it, which is string "hello world", then why after assign @_ to $item, the result is 1, seems the length of the array @_, but ($item) is the parameter itself,

Comment: This answered by [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/589924)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different assignment operators, the scalar assignment operator and the list assignment operator.  If what's to the left of `=` is a list, hash, array, or slice, it is a list assignment.  Otherwise, it is a scalar assignment.

A scalar assignment gives its right operand scalar context.  In scalar context, an array evaluates to the number of elements in the array.

Comment: so $item is a scalar, but ($item) is a list ?

Comment: yes.  though in general `()` just affect precedence and don't "make" a list, this is one of a couple places where they syntactically make there be a different operator