# Perl: Expression precedence and evaluation

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
$codelist = 00;

$OK = '0';
$OK = () = $codelist =~ /$OK/g;

print "$OK\n"; #answer is 2.
```

How does the expression `$OK = () = $codelist =~ /$OK/g` is evaluated?
What is the order of precedence?

Comment: It prints "1" on my system.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera How do you get 1?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera because $codelist = 00; means $codelist = 0; unless you write like $codelist = '00';

Comment: @Samy what precedence are you referring to?

Comment: @Pradeep I want to know which part of the expression $OK = () = $codelist =~ /$OK/g is evaluated first? What does the () to $OK?

Comment: In fact this piece of code is part of a plugin which executes a command on 2 nodes et store the exit code in $codelist. That's why it has 00 which are the exit code from the 2 nodes.

Comment: `$codelist = 00;` assigns the number zero to `$codelist`, and zero stringifies to `0`. The match operator is therefore matching against the string `0`. Use `$codelist = '00';` to get the match operator to match against the string `00`.

Answer (score 5):

`B::Deparse` can show you precedence if you ever get confused.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '$OK = () = "00" =~ /0/g'
($OK = (() = ('00' =~ /0/g)));
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at `perldoc perlop`, there is the following [precedence chart](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity):

```
left        terms and list operators (leftward)
left        ->
nonassoc    ++ --
right       **
right       ! ~ \ and unary + and -
left        =~ !~
left        * / % x
left        + - .
left        << >>
nonassoc    named unary operators
nonassoc    < > <= >= lt gt le ge
nonassoc    == != <=> eq ne cmp ~~
left        &
left        | ^
left        &&
left        || //
nonassoc    ..  ...
right       ?:
right       = += -= *= etc. goto last next redo dump
left        , =>
nonassoc    list operators (rightward)
right       not
left        and
left        or xor
```

From that chart, we look up `=~` and `=` because those are the only operators you have here.

`=~` is tighter binding, so that gets evaluated first `$OK = () = ($codelist =~ /$OK/g);`

Then `=`in `left` order...

```
($OK = () = ($codelist =~ /$OK/g));
($OK = (() = ($codelist =~ /$OK/g)));
```

Another helpful tool mentioned in other answers is `B::Deparse` with the `-p` option. Still, it is a good idea to be familiar with the above chart, or at least know where to reference it.

As a side note, the `=()=` is a somewhat common idiom, so much so that it has an entry in the [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse) distribution as the "Goatse" (don't Google that) or "Saturn" secret operator; it is essentially used to force list context to the right side, usually to return the count (since the left side is a scalar).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your example-code starts with

```
$codelist = '00';
```

The code

```
$OK = () = $codelist =~ /$OK/g;
```

first matches $codelist against 0 **globally** so it returns ALL matches. 
But that is only true, when called in a list-context. Otherwise, it would only return whether it matches or not. The assignment-trick with

```
$OK= () = ...
```

sets the list-context for the evaluation and evaluates the returned array in the scalar context (which results in the number of elements).

So when you remove the /g in the match, or the () = in the assingement you get 1.

Comment: Re "*evaluates the returned array in the scalar context*", That is wrong. 1) The match op returns a number of scalars, not an array. 2) Only *operators* are evaluated, not *values*. Converting a value is called *casting*, not *evaluating*. And casting into scalar context isn't a thing Perl ever does. What is really happening is that the *list assignment* is being evaluated in scalar context, which causes it to return the number of scalars returned by its RHS. See [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/589924) for more details

Comment: According to your explanation, `my @a = localtime; say scalar(@a);` and `say scalar(localtime);` should both output the same thing, but they don't.

Comment: about 1)  try ```perl -MData::Dumper -e "print Dumper ['0sdfsadfaf0'=~/./g]"```

Comment: What about it? `[]` creates an array populated by the scalars returned by the match operator, it creates a reference to the array, and it returns the reference. `Dumper` is called to create a string from that reference, the referenced array, and the scalars within. That string is printed to STDOUT by `print`. What part of that has anything to do with what I said?

Comment: I meant: "the match op (in list context) does not return a number." Obviously we have a language problem. What I meant is: The match-op with the /g modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on the context. In list context, it returns a list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. If there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern. (citing from https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)