# Unable to close file handle in Perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl as I was trying to create a text file in a sub-directory named as data inside a directory named as a test, I have tried to write the following code, the code is as follows:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
my $path = abs_path();
my @file = open(my $fh, '>>', '$path/test/data') or die "unable to create text file $!";
print $fh;
close $fh or die "unable to close file $fh $!\n";
```

It gave me the following error:-

```
unable to close file GLOB(0x1d5ea68) Bad file descriptor
```

Please it would be really helpful and appreciated if you can explain what is happening here? and how can it be solved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with reading https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print and also look up what `open` returns.

Comment: Improper use of `open` and `print` - [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open), [print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print)

Comment: You don't need to use a module, or a fancy path to create a new file, just open `test/data` and it will automatically use a path relative to where the Perl program is.

Comment: @TLP - Not relative to the current directory?

Comment: @JimDavis Those two will be the same unless you change directory.

Comment: @TLP - Or execute the script from another directory.

Comment: @JimDavis Right, the correct phrase would be "relative to the current working directory".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open` failed, so `$fh` doesn't contain a valid file handle, and this is causing `close` to fail.

---

`open` is returning an error, but you aren't being notified about it because your check is incorrect. Because `open` always returns a value, the list assignment always returns 1, so the `die` could never be evaluated. (See [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/589924) if you want more details.)

Replace

```perl
my @file = open(...)
    or die "unable to create text file $!";
```

with

```perl
open(...)
    or die "unable to create text file $!";
```

---

As for why `open` is failing, the reason is surely that the path `$path/test/data` doesn't exist. You are literally looking for a directory named `$path` because single-quoted string literals don't interpolate.

Replace

```perl
'$path/test/data'
```

with

```perl
"$path/test/data"
```

or simply

```perl
'test/data'
```

since `$path` just contains the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but I like to use the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module for file I/O.  It's much easier to use than raw open calls, and you don't have to hunt for separate modules for most tasks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny qw(path cwd);    # methods mkpath and remove_tree are available

my $file = cwd->child('test', 'data');
my $fh = $file->opena;  # dies on failure
print $fh;
close $fh or die "unable to close file $fh $!\n";

# But even easier to not bother with open/close and just do something like:
$file->append('...');
```

Answer (score 0):

What that error is saying is that `$fh` is not an open file handle.  The `GLOB...` part of the error message is the stringification of the file handle.  Most likely `$path/test/` doesn't exist so `$fh` is never opened.  `Open` will not create directory components, only files.  Check for it with `-e` first and create it with `mkdir` or `make_path` if necessary.

Your `open or die` clause doesn't work because you are capturing the `open` output into an array and that is what is evaluated by `or`.

I commend you for learning Perl to accomplish your task.  Here is what you should be reading to solve these problems and continue on your path.

https://perldoc.pl/perl  https://perldoc.pl/functions/open  https://perldoc.pl/functions

HTH

Comment: Re "*[an array] is evaluated by `or`*", Close, but no. `or`'s operand is a list assignment, not an array. A list assignment in scalar context returns the number of elements returned by its right-hand side, which is always one here.

Comment: Re "*Most likely `$path/test/` doesn't exist*", So very true, but I don't think you noticed the OP is literally looking for a subdirectory named `$path`. The problem is the use of single-quotes.

Comment: Here is the deparse.  `((my(@file) = open(my $fh, '>>', '$path/test/data')) or die(('unable to create text file ' . $!)));`  The `or` is checking `@file` in scalar context to decide whether to evaluate its RHS (die).  `@file` contains the return value of `open` which is `undef`.  You are right about the single quotes.

Comment: Re "*The or is checking @file in scalar context*", No, this is completely wrong. For starters, `@file` is evaluated in list context. And secondly, `=` is clearly `or`'s operand.  The assignment has to be the last thing done before doing `or`. You can't do the assignment until you've evaluated `@file`. Would you claim that `f() + g()` returns `f()`? No. Well `@file = ...` doesn't return `@file`.

Comment: Think of it like this: `or(lassign(@file, open))`. Your interpretation is clearly disproven with `() = open(...) or die;` According to you, that should always `die` because `()` in scalar context is false. But not, it never dies because a list assignment in scalar context returns the number of scalars returned by its RHS. See [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/589924) if you're still confused.

Comment: Re "*Check for it with `-e` first and create it with `mkdir` or `make_path` if necessary.*" Bad advice!! Shouldn't use `-e` in that situation. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960518/589924) for why and a better approach. Sorry, there are just too many problems with this answer. (Missing the actual problem, incorrect explanation of how assignment works, and bad suggestion to use `-e`.)

Comment: You are technically correct that the `or` *opcode* takes the return value of the `aassign` *opcode* in order to short circuit.  That is an implementation detail and doesn't change anything about my answer. `@file` will *always* contain whatever was returned by the RHS.  Semantically, boolean `@file` is what is compared by `or` as the deparse clearly shows.  The null list assignment is just an artifact of how list assignment was implemented; it's parser abuse.  It should be illegal syntax IMHO.

Comment: 99% of the time you do not have to check for file test race conditions.  However if you want to check EEXIST that is very laudable.

Comment: 100% of the time, you don't have to do extra work for nothing. mkdir already does an existence check. Doing a second one is pointless

Comment: @ikegami I didn't know that!