# How to retrieve the captured substrings from a capturing group that may repeat?

Tags: c++, regex, pcre2

I'm sorry I found it difficult to express this question with my poor English. So, let's go directly to a simple example.

Assume we have a subject string `"apple:banana:cherry:durian"`. We want to match the subject and have `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4` become `"apple"`, `"banana"`, `"cherry"` and `"durian"`, respectively. The pattern I'm using is `^(\w+)(?::(.*?))*$`, and `$1` will be `"apple"` as expected. However, `$2` will be `"durian"` instead of `"banana"`.

Because the subject string to match doesn't need to be 4 items, for example, it could be `"one:two:three"`, and `$1` and `$2` will be `"one"` and `"three"` respectively. Again, the middle item is missing.

What is the correct pattern to use in this case? By the way, I'm going to use PCRE2 in C++ codes, so there is no `split`, a Perl built-in function. Thanks.

Comment: You can't capture them as separate groups. All you can do is put a capturing group around the quantified group. This will retrieve them as a single string.

Comment: Btw, if you so wanted you can still split a string by `:` in C++ of course. It's nowhere near as clean and easy as in Perl (or Python, etc) but it's no big deal either.

Comment: @zdim Both Boost.Regex and std::regex are able to split the strings easily, but their syntax, even in Perl-style mode, are a little bit different than Perl-style regex. In this aspect, PCRE is better, IMO.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I thought there might be a way to get all substrings captured by `(...)*` . Guess only the last match counts.

Comment: @Cody "_(regex)...are able to split the strings easily_"  --- sure, I meant without regex.  I edited my answer a lot and added full C++ examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input contains strictly items of interest separated by `:`, like `item1:item2:item3`, as the attempt in the question indicates, then you can use the regex pattern

```
[^:]+
```

which matches consecutive characters which are not `:`, so a substring up to the first `:`.  That may need to capture as well, `([^:]+)`, depending on the overall approach.  How to use this to get *all* such matches depends on the language.<sup>†</sup>

In C++ there are different ways to approach this.  Using [std::regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str{R"(one:two:three)"};
    std::regex r{R"([^:]+)"};

    std::vector<std::string> result{};

    auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), r);
    auto end = std::sregex_iterator();
    for(; it != end; ++it) {
        auto match = *it;
        result.push_back(match[0].str());
    }

    std::cout << "Input string: " << str << '\n';
    for(auto i : result)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Prints as expected.

One can also use [std::regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search), even as it returns at first match -- by iterating over the string to move the search start after every match

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str{"one:two:three"};
    std::regex r{"[^:]+"};

    std::smatch res;

    std::string::const_iterator search_beg( str.cbegin() );
    while ( regex_search( search_beg, str.cend(), res, r ) )
    {
        std::cout << res[0] << '\n';  
        search_beg = res.suffix().first;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(With this string and regex we don't need the [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) so I've removed them here.)

---

<sup>†</sup>  This question was initially tagged with `perl` (with no c++), also with a mention of it in text; the original version of this answer referred to Perl with

```
/([^:]+)/g
```

The `//` are pattern delimiters.  The `/g` "modifier" is for "global," to find all matches.

When this expression is bound ([=~](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators)) to a variable with a target string, or to a string literal or to an expression yielding a scalar, then the whole expression returns a list of matches when used in a context in which a list is expected. Thus it can be directly assigned to an array variable, where the [list assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/4653379) itself provides the context

```
my @captures = $string =~ /[^:]+/g;
```

(when this is used literally as shown then the capturing `()` aren't needed)

Assigning to an array provides this "[list context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context)."  If the matching is used in a "scalar context," in which a single value is expected, like in the condition for an `if` test or being assigned to a scalar variable, then a single true/false is returned (usually `1` or `''`, empty string).

Answer (score 2):

Repeating a capture group will only capture the value of the last iteration. Instead, you might make use of the `\G` anchor to get consecutive matches.

If the whole string can only contain word characters separated by colons:

```
(?:^(?=\w+(?::\w+)+$)|\G(?!^):)\K\w+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^` Assert start of string
  - `(?=\w+(?::\w+)+$)` Assert from the current position 1+ word characters and 1+ repetitions of `:` and 1+ word characters till the end of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^):` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start and match `:`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\K\w+` Forget what is matched so far, and match 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BLu5ha/1)

To allow only words as well from the start of the string, and allow other chars after the word chars:

```
\G:?\K\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t9rHdV/1)