# why can't I work with (@_) directly and why does creating $item not pass the passed values as scalar?

Tags: perl, average

```
sub average {
    my $uebergeben = (@_);
    my $verrechnen = 0; 
    
    foreach my $item (@_){
        $verrechnen += $item;
    }

    my $scalardef = $verrechnen;
    my $average = $scalardef/$uebergeben;
    print "$average\n";
}

my @array = 20;
my @hallo = 10;

average(@array,@hallo);
```

Why does the variable `$verrechnen` have to be created outside the foreach loop?

Why is `$verrechnen += (@_)` not possible and why is `$item` not in scalar context?

Comment: 1) This code does not compile: there is a missing `}` (the one that should close the foreach loop). 2) What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the variable `$verrechnen` have to be created outside the foreach loop?

Because you want it to exist longer than a pass of the loop.

---

> Why is `$verrechnen += (@_)` not possible

This is perfectly valid syntax.

Evaluating an array in scalar context returns the number of elements in it, so this adds the number of elements in `@_` to `$verrechnen`.

For example, if you pass four arguments, `@_` will have four elements, and `$verrechnen += (@_)` will add four to `$verrechnen`.

Of course, that's not what you want to do here.

---

> why is `$item` not in scalar context?

Why would you even ask that? `$item` is not context-sensitive. It does exactly the same thing in scalar context, list context and void context.

Anyway, `$item` is used twice.

The idea of context doesn't make much sense for `for my $item` (since it's not in an expression), so let's ignore this use.

The other use is in `$verrechnen += $item;`, where `$item` is evaluated in scalar context as per [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/589924).

---

Simplified:

```perl
sub average {
    my $sum = 0;
    $sum += $_ for @_;
    return $sum/@_;
}
```