# perl glob files in directory

Tags: perl, glob

I am using glob to read `*_file.log` exist in certain directory but below code seems not working.

Example path having these few files:

```
/user/home/xpath/logs/
abc_file.log
def_file.log
x.txt
```

Code:

```
my $home = "/user/home";

if (glob ("${home}/xpath/logs/\*_file.log")){
print "work\n";
}
else {
print "something wrong\n"
}
```

Comment: `if glob` makes no sense. See docs for how `glob` behaves in scalar context.

Comment: The slash in `"\*"` is useless since `"\*"` is the same thing as `"*"`. But worse, the slash is extremely confusing because it looks like you're trying to prevent the `*` from having its normal effect. Get rid of that useless, confusing slash.

Comment: @ikegami, i am thinking to use `-e` in `if`, but not sure if it works for wildcard * character `if (-e "$home/xpath/logs/\*_file.log")`

Comment: i thought the slash required for `*` ?

Comment: Only `$`, `@`, `\ ` and the delimiter(s) are special in double-quoted strings. No other non-word character needs to be escaped. /// You also don't want to escape it for the glob, which would be `"\\*"` (to produce `\*`) because you want `*` to match "anything", not just `*`.

Comment: The `*` does not need to be escaped in a double-quoted string. Escaping it does no harm in this case, but simpler code is easier to debug. The curly brackets around `home` are also not needed because it is not followed by a word character. That said, when I run your script it prints `"work\n"`. The only modification I made was to replace your value of `$home` with `getcwd` because I'm running a variant of Unix that does not use `/home` and does not let me muck around with the root easily.

Comment: @user20284150, The OP's code is indeed buggy. As mentioned earlier, it makes no sense to use `if glob`

Comment: @ikegami. so you mean `if (-e "$xpath/logs/*_file.log")` works?

Comment: Where did you get that from? I didn't talk about `stat` (`-e`) at all. It expects a file name, so that checks if there's a file named `.../logs/*_file.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained, all matches from the [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) need be retrieved. Given that `glob` is a "very" global creature with long memory better use it in list context to exhaust its return right away, and then investigate it.  One way to do what the question tries

```
if ( my @entries = glob "$home/xpath/logs/*_file.log" ) {
    print "file: $_\n" for @entries;
}
else {
    print "No such entries found\n"
}
```

I cleaned up some of unneeded syntax elements.

A few comments

- If you really mean to use the home directory, the environment variable is available in the [%ENV hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25ENV), as `$ENV{HOME}` (or see [File::HomeDir](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::HomeDir))
- The [feature say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say) adds a newline to prints making them far nicer. For example, we can say

  ```
  say for @files;
  ```

  It need be enabled by `use feature qw(say);`, or by `use`-ing a Perl version 5.10 or newer, or by `use`-ing some of a number of packages/frameworks that enable it
- Once you reach for `glob` also have a look at [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob), which provides a drop-in replacement that handles spaces in names nicely.

Comment: `$ENV{HOME}` will be the current user's home dir instead of a hard coded one, which may be a notable difference. As I recall you can also use `~/` to emulate that, but I suppose that might be OS specific.

Comment: @TLP "_which may be a notable difference_" -- indeed, which is why I introduce that by saying "_If you really mean to use the home directory_".  The `~` doesn't work as home -- it will "work" though -- as a string :).  So once it's used for a filesystem entry it will look for an entry named that way.  From what I recall there are modules that interpret it as home directory. (I don't think it's worthed.  The `~` is a shell thing and I think it's best left that way.)

Comment: "_interpret it as home directory_" -- `glob` and `File::Glob` do (but I wouldn't recommend using that)

Answer (score 1):

Using `if glob` is wrong.

```
$ ls
a.log
b.log

$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'
   sub test { say "$_[0]: ", glob( $_[0] ) ? "at least one match" : "no matches" }
   test( "*.log" );
   test( "*.txt" );
   test( "*.log" );
'
*.log: at least one match      # Correct
*.txt: at least one match      # Incorrect
*.log: no matches              # Incorrect and a contradiction
```

`glob` in scalar context acts as an iterator.

- The first time it's called, it returns the first match.
- The second time it's called, it returns the second match (regardless of the argument).
- When it's called after all results have been returned, it returns `undef`.

If you're going to use `glob`, you're going to have to get all the results, not just the first.

For example, the following uses the [`scalar( () = ... )` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564429/589924) to call `glob` in list context (getting all the results) and count the number of items it returns.

```
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'
   sub test { say "$_[0]: ", ( () = glob( $_[0] ) ) ? "at least one match" : "no matches" }
   test( "*.log" );
   test( "*.txt" );
   test( "*.log" );
'
*.log: at least one match
*.txt: no matches
*.log: at least one match
```

Comment: Somewhere, someone (maybe you) listed all the Perl functions with state. I can't remember where I saw that.

Comment: @brian d foy, If so, I don't remember. I can just think of `glob`, scalar `..`, scalar `...` right now. Indirectly, m//g sets `pos($_)` (where `$_` is the bound var).

Comment: any other suggestion other than glob?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid glob? I can't suggest solutions to a problem you didn't identify! Not sure the comments is the place to ask new questions, though...