# perl file not exist check

Tags: file, perl

I want to check if pass file exist and there is no fail file in certain path. Is there any operator for file not exist?

```
example path:
x.pass
y.fail

my $filepath = "path/to/file/";
if (-e "$filepath/*pass" && <*fail not exist>){
  #do something
}
```

Comment: `if ( ! -e path ) ...`

Comment: `-e` is the operator for "File exists" and you are using it already. Your if-statement basically would check then if "File exists && File does not exist" - which is always false.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, the OP's question is more like "file1 exists, and file2 doesn't exist"

Comment: Nope, no such operator.  Can use `not -e $file` (or `! -e $file` for tighter precedence).  Watch for precedence when using complex conditions; that `&&` binds more tightly than `and`.  For example, `if (-e $f1 and not -e $f2)` is fine.  When in doubt use extra parenthesis.  And test carefully.

Comment: (Regarding the mention of precedence in my previous comment--  In this particular case precedence rules don't matter, as `&& not` can't do anything other than what is needed -- `not` still negates what follows it and then that is `&&`-ed with the preceding condition.  But it would make me very uncomfortable seeing the higher precedence `&&` tying conditions which themselves use the lower precedence `not` (or others).  It's errors waiting to happen)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will use ! e in this case

Answer (score 0):

`stat`/`-e` gets information about a file. It returns false if there's an error, including if it doesn't exist. It returns error `ENOENT` if the file doesn't exist.

```perl
if ( !-e $path ) {
   die( "`$path` doesn't exist\n" ) if $!{ENOENT};  # Optional.
   die( "Can't stat `$path`: $!\n" );
}
```

or

```perl
if ( !stat( $path ) ) {
   die( "`$path` doesn't exist\n" ) if $!{ENOENT};  # Optional.
   die( "Can't stat `$path`: $!\n" );
}
```

Note that you ask how to check if a file exists. If you're asking about globs as your example suggests, [you already know how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75627505/589924).